# Force IE8 to Redraw/Repaint after margin-left

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm in IE8 and setting the `margin-left` of an element to `-1000px;`

The `DOM` does not update. If I go to the inspector, uncheck the box next `margin-left` in the `Trace Styles` section, and then recheck the box - it updates.

I've tried everything from setting `opacity` afterward, to `display`, to `visibility`. I even tried `zoom`. I also tried changing those properties of the element's parent with no success.

Comment: Also tried detaching from dom and then reattaching

Comment: sounds like a rendering bug to me, can't you do a workaround instead of having a  -1000px negative margin?

Comment: That was my workaround since the plugin ( `iscroll` ) I was modifying would use `position absolute` and `top` and `left` but a wrapping element with `overflow hidden` would fail since the child was absolute. I just ended up doing a graceful degradation that doesn't use the plugin for IE<9. However if someone has an answer to this I'd be so happy

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, leading to excess bile and hatred for microsoft developers.

This isn't good for the soul or my environment, fortunately I found a workaround.

I too had margins not being applied, but when you changed or add css in F12 Dev Tools it sorted its life out.

my example was using js to set CSS then add the element like so -

`this.pvText.style.setAttribute("margin-top","80px");
 this.pvTextPlaceholder.node.appendChild(this.pvText);`

resetting the cssText seemed to force a re-draw -

`var tmp = this.pvText.style.cssText;
    this.pvText.style.cssText = "";
    this.pvText.style.cssText = tmp;`

ahhh and on a Friday morning..... yessss.. ^_^

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fEoFlhm1u4